MailMessage returns 400 error but anonymous type does not
I wrote a WinForms frontend for an MS Access database that sends project status emails to my employees. Worked great for years using smtp.  I'm trying to upgrade the program to use MS Graph API to send these emails without smtp.  I've figured out the authenticating part and can send emails successfully when I create a message using anonymous type:
var emailMessage = new
            {
                message = new
                {
                    subject = subject,
                    body = new
                    {
                        contentType = "Text",
                        content = body
                    },
                    toRecipients = new[]
                    {
                        new
                        {
                            emailAddress = new
                            {
                                address = userEmail
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            };

Where userEmail, subject and body are predefined strings.
The serialized json string sent to graph looks like this:
"{\"message\":{\"subject\":\"New Job History for Job: 102F-001 Perez Road\",\"body\":{\"contentType\":\"Text\",\"content\":\"New Job History entry for Job: 102F-001 Perez Road\\r\\n\\r\\nfixesbythinking 4/13/2024 10:42:00 AM - test\"},\"toRecipients\":[{\"emailAddress\":{\"address\":\"userEmail\"}}]}}"

However, when I use the MailMessage class
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

message.Subject = "This is the Subject";
message.Body = "This is the Body";
message.To.Add(userEmail);

The serialized json string is:
"{\"From\":null,\"Sender\":null,\"ReplyTo\":null,\"ReplyToList\":[],\"To\":[{\"DisplayName\":\"\",\"User\":\"fixesbythinking\",\"Host\":\"xxxxx.xxx\",\"Address\":\"fbt@xxxxx.xxx\"}],\"Bcc\":[],\"CC\":[],\"Priority\":0,\"DeliveryNotificationOptions\":0,\"Subject\":\"New Job History for Job: 102F-001 Perez Road\",\"SubjectEncoding\":null,\"Headers\":[],\"HeadersEncoding\":null,\"Body\":\"New Job History entry for Job: 102F-001 Perez Road\\r\\n\\r\\nfixesbythinking 4/9/2024 6:42:39 AM - Test\",\"BodyEncoding\":{\"IsSingleByte\":true,\"BodyName\":\"us-ascii\",\"EncodingName\":\"US-ASCII\",\"HeaderName\":\"us-ascii\",\"WebName\":\"us-ascii\",\"WindowsCodePage\":1252,\"IsBrowserDisplay\":false,\"IsBrowserSave\":false,\"IsMailNewsDisplay\":true,\"IsMailNewsSave\":true,\"EncoderFallback\":{\"DefaultString\":\"?\",\"MaxCharCount\":1},\"DecoderFallback\":{\"DefaultString\":\"?\",\"MaxCharCount\":1},\"IsReadOnly\":true,\"CodePage\":20127},\"BodyTransferEncoding\":-1,\"IsBodyHtml\":false,\"Attachments\":[],\"AlternateViews\":[]}"


And this produces the 400 Bad Request error.  I'm sure there's got to be either something missing from the string or maybe a bad value within it (other than json syntax error - I checked that).
I've tried cutting and pasting values for email address, subject, body, from, to, etc and it always works when I use the anonymous type, but never using MailMessage.  My guess is there is one or more properties in MailMessage I need to set values for, but I've been searching online for days and can't seem to find what it would be.

you have to have a sender in the message, add a From email

You are still using SMTP in the backend of the application.  Microsoft Graph is creating a front end from Client to Microsoft Graph Server using HTTP.  Then backend is a connection from Microsoft Graph to email server using SMTP.  The HTTP body in the frontend is HTTP email that gets sent to the Email Server using SMTP.  The frontend body needs to have ALL the required info that you had using SMTP alone.

I think you also need a credential with the Mail Message.  You can't have a SMTP email without credentials.  Your mail message is missing the credentials.

Thanks @WalterVerhoeven, but I don't think that's correct for MS Graph.  Part of the httpClient call references the user's email and that's the From address. codevar response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"{graphApiEndpoint}/users/{userEmail}/sendMail", new StringContent(jsonMessage, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));code I added a From email, but Graph still shows it being send from {useremail}

@jdweng That does not explain why the anonymous type works, it only has minimal info in it.  Also, the credentials for Graph involve application permissions on Entra, tenantID, clientID and clientSecret.  I have that part working fine (the anonymous type works).  I didn't post the code for authentication because that's a common question and I have that part working.  The problem is not credentials, it's in the json serialized from the mail message.  Something's missing I think.

My workaround is to use the anonymous type to setup an email and then use a foreach to loop through all recipients.  I send a separate email to each user instead of one email to multiple recipients.  This does work, not ideal or efficient, but it's working until I can figure out what's missing from the string when I serialize a MailMessage object to json.

You did not post the controller code.  You need to look at the Anonymous and [Authenticate] portion of the controller to see what is actually happening.
